# Order by a text string excluding hyphen in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL query with this line

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY text_string ASC
```

The strings e.g.

```
L-IP Readme
LIP-3ECTC Firmware
L-INX Readme
LINX-150 Firmware
LINX-120 Firmware
```

What I get:

```
L-INX Readme
L-IP Readme
LINX-120 Firmware
LINX-150 Firmware
LIP-3ECTC Firmware
```

I want that the order does not consider the hyphen:

```
L-INX Readme
LINX-120 Firmware
LINX-150 Firmware
L-IP Readme
LIP-3ECTC Firmware
```

I did this with:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY REPLACE (text_string,'-','') ASC
```

Is there a better, optimized solution with large tables?

Comment: Add a new column to the table with the chars removed you don't want to be taken in account to order. Space is cheap, "REPLACE in ORDER BY" is expensive. Don't forget to add an index!

Comment: Thanks for your respond! I agree, but unfortunately I can't expand the table.

Comment: I think it's the only fast way. Everything else would result in string manipulation during the execution which is slow per se. Why' you not allowed? Convince your boss ;)